# Hsqldb has no data when populated via maven liquibase plugin

Tags: maven, hsqldb, liquibase

I've created schema and populated it via Maven liquibase plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/config/db.config.properties</propertyFile>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Properties file:

```
driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
#HSQLDB Embedded in file
url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/dataFile
username: SA
password:
```

As I see in the output when invoke `mvn liquibase:update`:

```
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/dataFile
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: ChangeSet src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::1::sav ran successfully in 7ms
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: ChangeSet src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::2::sav ran successfully in 3ms
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
INFO 24.04.13 10:00:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

`db.changelog-master.xml` contains:

```
 <include file="src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
```

`db.changelog-1.0.xml` contains:

```
 <changeSet id="1" author="sav">
        <createTable tableName="testTable">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="2" author="sav">
        <insert tableName="testTable">
            <column name="id" value="1"/>
            <column name="name" value="First String"/>
        </insert>
        <insert tableName="testTable">
            <column name="id" value="2"/>
            <column name="name" value="Second String"/>
            <column name="active" value="false"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
```

It seems everything is OK. Now i'm going to `src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/` folder and see three files:

```
dataFile.log
dataFile.properties
dataFile.script
```

But I don't see a `CREATE TABLE testTable` DDL statement in the `dataFile.script`. 
Next in Intelli IDEA I configure datasource plugin (set jdbc hsql driver, url: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/dataFile`, user: sa ). Connect it, invoke query:

```
SELECT * FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES;
```

1. I cannot see the table I try to create.
2. The value of hsqldb_type field for each table - is MEMORY. I expect it to be FILE of something similar.

Any ideas?:)

PS:
1. Maven repository returns **HSQLDB** as the first search result, and its last version is 1.8.0.10. Actually I had to use **HSQLDB DATABASE** with its 2.2.9 version. It solved the problem of table creation.
2. I had to use an absolute path to the file AND the ';ifexists=true' property to connect to the existing database in IDEA datasource plugin. As a result my url connection string in the property file differ from the same used in the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful about the use of file paths:

This is a relative path:

```
driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
#HSQLDB Embedded in file
url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/dataFile
```

This is an absolute path within the current drive:

```
Next in Intelli IDEA I configure datasource plugin (set jdbc hsql driver, url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/dataFile, user: sa )
```

Try using absolute paths.

Apart from that, in your attempt to check things in an existing database, connect explicitly requiring the database to exist by adding `;ifexists=true` to the connection URL.

As we are not sure Liquibase shuts down the database correctly or not, you can add a property to the Liquibase connection URL to ensure data is written fully `;hsqldb.write_delay=false`. We are assuming you are using HSQLDB 2.x for this property.

Answer (score 0):

With HSQLDB 1.8.x, liquibase <= 3.2.0 never read tables on database.
This is because `catalog` should be set `null` when retrieve JDBC metadata.
We could not force the catalog to be null, because the method `AbstractJdbcDatabase.correctSchema()` should not set `catalog=schema`, if `supportCatalogs()` return false.

I will post a issue for this.